# Read data from MySQL via Vec<Row>

Tags: mysql, rust

What's the best (simple, safe & efficient) way to read data from MySQL via `Vec<Row>`?

Here is an example function that uses a vector of (specific) tuples:

```
fn read_recs(tx: &mut Transaction) -> Result<HashMap<i64, String>> {
    let q = format!("SELECT id, name FROM some_table");
    let rows: Vec<(i64, String)> = tx.query(q)?;
    let mut res = HashMap::new();
    for r in rows {
        res.insert(r.0, r.1);
    }
    Ok(res)
}
```

For simple queries I've found that approach good enough (as well as `query_map()`), but for queries returning more columns, I'd prefer to directly read into `Vec<Row>` and then somehow read the values in a simple (not too verbose) fashion like this:

```
let rows: Vec<Row> = tx.query(q)?;
for r in rows {
    let id: i64 = extract(r, 0)?;
    let name: String = extract(r, 1)?;
}
```

or maybe even this:

```
let rows: Vec<Row> = tx.query(q)?;
for r in rows {
    let id: i64 = extract(r, "id")?;
    let name: String = extract(r, "name")?;
}
```

Question is, what would that `extract` look like so that it either reads the data successfully or returns an *error*? I do *not* want it to panic in case, for example, the query returns `NULL` in a situation where I only expect not-null values. And obviously I would prefer *not* to have to deal with `Option<...>` values every time I read data from a field, as that would make my code way too verbose.

BTW I use [`Anyhow`](https://docs.rs/anyhow) if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I quite understand the question, but wouldn't this work?

```rust
fn extract<I, T>(row: &Row, index: I) -> anyhow::Result<T>
where
    I: ColumnIndex,
    T: FromValue,
{
    row.get_opt(index).ok_or(ValueAlreadyTakenErrorOrSomething)?
}
```